# How to play a consecutive series of images after a click/touch in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net

I am working on a program for a psychology lab where I need to play a series of images (separated from a gif) after the original image is clicked. This is the section of code that concerns this.

```
Private Sub bubble_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles bubble.Click
    My.Computer.Audio.Play(ExcellentSound)
    ResetTouchCounters()
    bubble.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile("1.JPG")
    Sleep(100)
    bubble.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile("2.JPG")
    Sleep(100)
    bubble.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile("3.JPG")
    Sleep(100)
    bubble.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile("4.JPG")
    Sleep(100)
    bubble.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile("5.JPG")
    Sleep(100)
    bubble.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile("6.JPG")
    Sleep(100)
    bubble.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile("7.JPG")
    Sleep(100)
    bubble.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile("8.JPG")
    Sleep(100)
    bubble.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile("9.JPG")
    Sleep(100)
    bubble.Location = New Point(689, 578)
    ' = New Point (timer3 value, timer 4 * .24)
End Sub
```

The image can successfully be clicked and relocates to the New Point, but the images I want to play after the click are skipped. I am drawing the images from a debug folder and no startup/ syntax errors are dected when I start the program. I am new to VB, so any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This is a result of not understanding the [message loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_loop_in_Microsoft_Windows) that underpins everything. The system code that runs your Click event handler is the same code that processes `WM_PAINT` messages for the `bubble` PictureBox. It can't process any new paint messages until you yield back control after the event handler finishes, and by this time you have already advanced to the final image.

Instead, add a [Timer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.timer?view=net-5.0) to the form that is not Enabled by default. Use the button click to start the timer, and move to the next image in the timer's `Elapsed` event. It might be tempting instead to add `DoEvents()` calls into the Click handler, but that is **NOT** the best option.

Comment: How should I format the timer in order for it to be activated by the click? Also, how do I use the elapsed function? I am unfamiliar with this feature. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: You create the `Elapsed` event handler similar to how you create a Click or other event handler. To start the timer, in the current click handler you have code similar to `MyTimer.Enabled = True`

Answer (score 0):

One natural way to do this is to change to using asynchronous code.  If you change your function signature to:

```
Private Async Sub bubble_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles bubble.Click
```

Then, you can replace each instance of `Sleep(100)` with `Await Task.Delay(100)`.

Behind the scenes, at every point where you `Await`, control is returned to the UI, which allows it to repaint (also see Joel's answer).  When the delay expires, your routine will resume at the point where it was suspended.

You do need to be careful about managing your UI.  Because the `Await`s return control to the UI, the user could interact with it, leading to re-entrant code.  But something that's timer-based would have the same issue.